# Mac Sierra : PHP 5.6 to PHP 7

Tags: php, macos, operating-system, upgrade

**Situation :**

phpinfo function show 7.1.1 version of php

php -v show 5.6.30 version of php

**Question :**

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: have you installed php with bower? You'r cli is outdated

Comment: only do that : https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/

Answer (score 2):

The php version that shows 7.1.1 version is showing your php that came along with xampp or mamp. Whereas the the version 5.6.30 is the php that pre-installed with os x sierra.

You can refer to this website to upgrade your php in os x sierra
https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-upgrade-your-version-of-php-to-7-0-on-macos-sierra-e1bfdea55a63